# What is the simplest example of multithreading using background worker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have googled this topic but i can't find any tutorial that i can understand...plz help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two VB.NET tutorials:
http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/2879/
 http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ffortino/Page105242009222549PM/Page1.aspx

Here the MSDN overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx
(Just select VB as your language, the msdn examples are quite basic)

Also see 101 samples for VB.NET:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789075
(See Base Class Libraries - Group 2 Samples for multithreading)